# Which one is the correct graph for $u[2-n]$?

Tags: discrete-signals

$u[n]$ is the unit step function in discrete form. I want to know which one of the following two is the correct waveshape for $u[2-n]$, where $k$ is a constant.

What's the answer? The top one is $u[n]$, the unit step function. So, what's the graph for $u[2-n]$, middle or bottom?

[image]

Comment: You know that $u[1]=1$ and $u[-1]=0$. Plug values of $n$ from your second and third axis so that the function argument is 1 and -1, and you'll see which one is right.

Comment: The second one is the right one -(n-2) = 2-n

Comment: For me, I will do the your first suggested operation: delay 2 samples then reversal, but the graph should be the bottom one.

Answer (score 8):

**HINT:** For which value of $n$ does the argument of $u[2-n]$ become zero? That's where the step occurs. For which values of $n$ is the argument non-negative? That's where your unit step equals $1$. If you think about it for a minute, it should become really easy.

Comment: Really?????????????? Need 15 characters...

Comment: @Moti: My comment was a reaction to your statement that the "second one" is the correct solution. I thought you meant the second of the two "solutions" (i.e. the last figure), so I thought you might want to reconsider your comment. Now I realize that you meant the first solution, i.e. the second figure from top, which is of course correct.

Answer (score 5):

**Basically, discrete unit step signal may be defined as:**
$$u[n] = 
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
&1 &\scriptstyle{\text{for n > 0}}\\
&0 &\scriptstyle{\text{for n < 0}}\\
\end{align}
\end{cases}$$
**Doing time reversing (inverse)**
$$u[-n] = 
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
&1 &\scriptstyle{\text{for -n > 0}}\\
&0 &\scriptstyle{\text{for -n < 0}}\\
\end{align}
\end{cases}$$
$$u[-n] = 
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
&1 &\scriptstyle{\text{for n < 0}}\\
&0 &\scriptstyle{\text{for n > 0}}\\
\end{align}
\end{cases}$$
**Now doing shifting by (+2)**
$$u[-n+2]=u[2-n] = 
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
&1 &\scriptstyle{\text{for n < 2}}\\
&0 &\scriptstyle{\text{for n > 2}}\\
\end{align}
\end{cases}$$
$Which\ gives\ you\ the\ second\ signal\ you\ stated\ in\ your\ question$

Answer (score 0):

Ya second one is correct
You have to remember just priority to do such silly questions
time reverse>time shifting>time scaling
And amplitude reverse /scaling/shifting can be done at any time

Comment: For linear systems, I think there is no priority among reverse, time shifting and time scaling. Don't they obey the commutative property?

Answer (score 0):

First of all , none of the answers are correct since the u[n] should be in dicrete form , since the options are given in continuous domain it is wrong, is we consider same as in a discrete domain then the answer is C  first u[-n] and then shift 2  two units to the left to -2 so the option C is correct